# model.ts best practice when exporting Angular 4 Module/Components

Tags: angular, typescript, module, model, components

I have a component library and I am exporting a module that requires an object to be passed into it. This object is typed as a class called `NavigationModel` and my `NavigationModule` exists to provide one major component

- NavigationComponent

The way I use the `NavigationComponent` in for instance a `app.component.ts` is like this:

```
<app-navigation-menu [navSettings]="navigationSettings">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-navigation-menu>
```

I require the user to pass in a `navigationObject`, it has some basic settings and values the component needs to work. Coming back to that model: `shared/model/navigation.Model.ts`

I would like for the user to new up this model inside the `app.component.ts`, something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.navItems = this.navData.getNavigationItems();
    this.navigationObject = new NavigationModel()
    this.navigationObject.navItems = this.navItems;
    this.navigationObject.logoImage = "assets/Logo.png";
    this.navigationObject.logoCondensedImage = "assets/Logo-Condensed.png";
  }
```

So my question is this:

How do I export this model from my component library, I use a `public_api.ts` to define each module I want to export, but I wouldn't export this model there would I?, something like:

```
export * from './src/app/modules/navigation/navigation.module'
export * from './src/app/modules/navigation/shared/models/navigation.model'
```

I feel like I should only export modules here, and that module should export my model maybe?

It would be nice if by simply importing my `NavigationModule` inside my `app.module.ts`, that I could somehow have the `NavigationModel` available in my `app.component.ts` and I could new() it up and the developer would easily be able to discover whatever properties they need to add by typing:

```
this.navigationObject.
```

and they would get a list from intellisense of what options were expected. What is the best way to provide a model for them to use in this scenario or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I have the same question, and have been searching for an answer - so I would be interested if you have managed to solve the problem?
Using the 'export * ...' option you suggested seems not to work (anyway, I can't _import_ navigation.model into another project).